# How can I convert bytes object to decimal or binary representation in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-conversion, byte, bytestream

I wanted to convert an object of type bytes to binary representation in python 3.x.

For example, I want to convert the bytes object `b'\x11'` to the binary representation `00010001` in binary (or 17 in decimal).

I tried this:

```
print(struct.unpack("h","\x11"))
```

But I'm getting:

```
error struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 2
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Starting from Python 3.2, you can use [`int.from_bytes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.from_bytes).

Second argument, `byteorder`, specifies [endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of your bytestring. It can be either `'big'` or `'little'`. You can also use `sys.byteorder` to get your host machine's native byteorder.

```py
import sys
int.from_bytes(b'\x11', byteorder=sys.byteorder)  # => 17
bin(int.from_bytes(b'\x11', byteorder=sys.byteorder))  # => '0b10001'
```

Comment: I tried finding the bit representation of a UUID using this method. When i used len function on that bit string, it came out to be 127. But UUID's are 128 bit numbers. Can you please explain why the length calculated was 127?

Comment: 0-127 is 128 numbers

Comment: if the bytes has leading zeros, this method does not work.

Comment: To achieve reverse operation is `INTEGER.to_bytes(..)`

Answer (score 11):

Iterating over a bytes object gives you 8 bit ints which you can easily format to output in binary representation:

```py
import numpy as np

>>> my_bytes = np.random.bytes(10)
>>> my_bytes
b'_\xd9\xe97\xed\x06\xa82\xe7\xbf'

>>> type(my_bytes)
bytes

>>> my_bytes[0]
95

>>> type(my_bytes[0])
int

>>> for my_byte in my_bytes:
>>>     print(f'{my_byte:0>8b}', end=' ')

01011111 11011001 11101001 00110111 11101101 00000110 10101000 00110010 11100111 10111111
```

A function for a hex string representation is builtin:

```
>>> my_bytes.hex(sep=' ')
'5f d9 e9 37 ed 06 a8 32 e7 bf'
```