# Python - Convert bytearray to binary data then select bits

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x

I would like to convert a bytearray in Python 3 in binary data in order to manipulate them.

For example, let's assume that we have the following:

`a = bytearray(b'\x10\x10\x10')`

Then:

a) I would like to display `a` in its binary form, such as
`b = 0b100000001000000010000`.

b) I would like to be able to select some bits from the previous data (where the least significant bit would correspond to `b[0]` somehow), e.g., `b[4:8] = 0b0001` .

How can we do that in Python?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert bytes object to decimal or binary representation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010682/how-can-i-convert-bytes-object-to-decimal-or-binary-representation-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Axe319

Your post only partly answers my question.

Thanks to you, I got:

```
import sys

a = bytearray(b'\x10\x10\x10')
b = bin(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder=sys.byteorder))

print(b)
0b100000001000000010000
```

Then, to select four bits, I found from [Python: How do I extract specific bits from a byte?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45220959/python-how-do-i-extract-specific-bits-from-a-byte):

```
def access_4bits(data, num):
    # access 4 bits from num-th position in data
    return bin(int(data, 2) >> num & 0b1111)

c = access_4bits(b, 4)

print(c)
0b1
```

Comment: Note that the name `state` should be changed to `a` to become `b = bin(int.from_bytes(a, byteorder=sys.byteorder))`

Comment: Edited! It was a typo. Thank you.