# i have a string that contains bytesarray now how do i typecast this string to a bytesarray? in python

Tags: python, encoding

i have a code that encrypts data and then i embed it into an image,
so when I was checking the encryption and decryption code that worked fine,
Also i used blowfish module for encryption.

now problem is that when I embed the data into the image and extract it,
It's a bytesarray in plaintext form,

```
b'\x98\xac\xc3ymQ_\x80\xcb\xec\x9c\x04\xc3@\x88\x93`j\x05\x96\x9d\xcb\x0ec\xb2\x9b(\xd9@\x9fI\x00\xc7h\xe3\x83\xbd0\r\xad}*t'
```

the above is a bytesarray in plaintext form,
So if I try to convert it to bytesarray again it will re-encode it and put the '\' between the characters that already have it and now this new bytesarray is not a normal bytesarray, and the data is corrupted.

```
bytearray(b"b\'\\x98\\xac\\xc3ymQ_\\x80\\xcb\\xec\\x9c\\x04\\xc3@\\x88\\x93`j\\x05\\x96\\x9d\\xcb\\x0ec\\xb2\\x9b(\\xd9@\\x9fI\\x00\\xc7h\\xe3\\x83\\xbd0\\r\\xad}*t\'")
```

So my question is that how do I typecast or convert the str to a bytesarray?
without changing the data.

Comment: You can use `eval(expr)` to achieve that. Be warned, though, that this can by made to execute any code, so make sure you know what you submit to it. Also, I think you shold try to understand _why_ you get the result as a string. If you can, it is better to fix this at the source.

Comment: ohh that, i purposefully made it to a string so that i can convert it to binary.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve]. Where your string comes from? Maybe it's a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) and could be prevented rather than solved?

Answer (score 1):

If I can understand your requirement then the following code snippet could help. Applied module [`ast` — Abstract Syntax Trees](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html):

import ast

```
bys=r"b'\x98\xac\xc3ymQ_\x80\xcb\xec\x9c\x04\xc3@\x88\x93`j\x05\x96\x9d\xcb\x0ec\xb2\x9b(\xd9@\x9fI\x00\xc7h\xe3\x83\xbd0\r\xad}*t'"
print( '↓↓↓', type(bys))
print( bys)
byb = ast.literal_eval(bys)
print( byb)
print( '↑↑↑', type(byb))
```

**Result**: `.\SO\68139330.py`

> ```
> ↓↓↓ <class 'str'>
> b'\x98\xac\xc3ymQ_\x80\xcb\xec\x9c\x04\xc3@\x88\x93`j\x05\x96\x9d\xcb\x0ec\xb2\x9b(\xd9@\x9fI\x00\xc7h\xe3\x83\xbd0\r\xad}*t'
> b'\x98\xac\xc3ymQ_\x80\xcb\xec\x9c\x04\xc3@\x88\x93`j\x05\x96\x9d\xcb\x0ec\xb2\x9b(\xd9@\x9fI\x00\xc7h\xe3\x83\xbd0\r\xad}*t'
> ↑↑↑ <class 'bytes'>
> ```

Comment: Ok so as the JohanL said i used eval now a new problem arose, apparently eval has some memory limitations and hence it breaks when the byte string is a certain length does literal_eval has that problem covered?

Comment: It doesn't work, is there a manual way of doing it, i get eol error because the byte string is too long.

Answer (score 0):

Okay anyone else trying to achieve this the other answers are correct provided you are working with a small byte string.

But as I wasn't and needed the theoretical unlimited byte string size
(I wanted it to be at-least 1000 lines of 25 words of 4 letters on average each).

So if you want to do the same then,
convert the Byte string to it's equivalent binary by below code:

```
def bitstring_to_bytes(s):
    return int(s, 2).to_bytes((len(s) + 7) // 8, byteorder='big')
```

Then reconstruct the byte string by

```
def bin2byte(bin_string):
    return bin(int.from_bytes(bit_string, byteorder="big"))
```

this can overcome the limitation with eval and can go way further than that.

I referred these posts from stack overflow:
byte string to binary: [How can I convert bytes object to decimal or binary representation in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010682/how-can-i-convert-bytes-object-to-decimal-or-binary-representation-in-python/45010936)

binary to byte string :[Convert binary string to bytearray in Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32675679/convert-binary-string-to-bytearray-in-python-3/32683047#32683047)