# Reading and converting files in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, file, binary

I want to be able to get a file(not just text files, I mean video files, word files, exe files etc...) and read its data in python. Then , I want to convert it to pure binary (1s and 0s) and then be able to decode that too.

I have tried just reading the file with

```
with open('a.mp4', 'rb') as f:
    ab = f.read()
```

and it seemed to work, but my function of

```
def toBinary(a):
  l,m=[],[]
  for i in a:
    l.append(ord(i))
  for i in l:
    m.append(int(bin(i)[2:]))
  return m
```

does not work on it, because I think ord() only works on text??? Not really sure

Comment: What exactly do you want? Print the file content in binary format like "10011011 00101000"?

Comment: Yes, I want to do that

Comment: You neither need `ord` nor `int` for this. Therefore you also don't need the list `l`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I convert bytes object to decimal or binary representation in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45010682/how-can-i-convert-bytes-object-to-decimal-or-binary-representation-in-python)